# How to retrieve the batch inserted rows with Spring jdbcTemplate batchUpdate

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbctemplate

I'm using Java spring jdbTemplate to batch insert rows, so far, i know it's not supported to use KeyHolder in batchUpdate, and get the auto-generated keys is not a part of jdbc specification, whether this feature is supported depends on the jdbc driver and database, so i'm thinking if there's another way to retrieve the inserted rows back, it's acceptable if we need another db query

here is the related dependency version i used:
Spring Boot 2.7.12
ojdbc8
Oracle Database

Comment: Normally have a table called batches_loaded(batch_id generated always as identity, batch_start_time date not null, batch_end_time date, descript_text varchar2(1000), table_loaded varchar2(255) not null). First insert into that table, then hold the batch_id and insert that batch_id also into the destination table in a specific column. I see no other way.

Comment: @BogdanDincescu is that possible if i get the sequence number i need in advance? i found it's possible to get sequence values in advance but i'm not sure if there's any concurrent issue

Answer (score -1):

i don't find an official solution for this, so finally i generate these id in advance and assign them to the records i need to insert, in this way i can avoid to get these id back after batch update...

Comment: Rather than posting this as an answer you should post it as a comment.  If you want it to be answer you should provide more details as to your solution including sample code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).